# HTML file is downloaded twice in one file

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following code in my controller:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$file = 'myfile.html';
$contentType = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
finfo_close($finfo);

$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', $contentType);
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.basename($file));
$response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
$response->headers->set('Expires', '0');
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate');
$response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
$response->headers->set('Content-Length', filesize($file));

$response->setContent(file_get_contents($file));
$response->send();
return $response;
```

When I run this code on my dev computer (Mac with PHP 5.3.15) I get the file I want with its content. But when I run it on my test server (Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.3.10) I still get the file, but the content is doubled (I get twice the file in one single file).

I found a way to get it to work using `$contentType = 'application/octet-stream';`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please sniff the network traffic and let us know if the files data is even transferred two times within the response body.

Comment: @hakre I just ran some tests with Wireshark and the file data is "encapsuled" twice in the server response...any idea?

Comment: Okay (wow), and how does the raw protocol interaction from the client side look like? Can you add it to your question? Also please add the HTTP request as seen in wireshark to the question (just the text), and for the response (sure you don't want to post all), somehow so that it is clear what that double-data looks like with the response.

Comment: From my nose: I'm not sure if you are reading the signs correctly here. Just saying. I have never seen a duplicate send of the response body. Check if the content-length response header matches with the length of the response body. If the server answers twice (here with a static HTML file?!), this *would* mean the server is awfully broken. Not that it's not possible, but would you consider that likely?

Comment: I might be wrong, but it looks to me like the data is actually being sent twice. First time with `$response->send();` and the second time with `return $response;` . What happens when you remove the `->send()` part?

Comment: @mogoman you are right! if you create an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @hakre thanks for your help. I don't know why the behavior is different on my dev computer but I tried the code on 2 different linux servers and the ouput was the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that these two lines do the same thing (in Symfony)

```
$response->send();
return $response;
```

I suggest removing the $response->send() line.